# How to add fold highlighting to .vimrc in vim

Tags: vim

I want to highlight my folded text.  If I use:

```
:highlight Folded ctermbg=black ctermfg=white cterm=bold
```

everything works ok, but when I add this line to my .vimrc:

```
highlight Folded ctermbg=black ctermfg=white cterm=bold
```

nothing happens (I mean after reopening vim). Any idea why?

Comment: Try `:verbose hi Folded` to see where the current highlight for `Folded` is defined. Most likely you have a color scheme that overrides the setting from vimrc.

Comment: Make sure to place the highlight line after you set your colorscheme.

Comment: I am not sure this is useful but you might also want to do a `:highlight clear Folded` before applying the new style.

Comment: Yes my colorscheme were overriding it, thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try `:verbose hi Folded` to see where the current highlight for `Folded` is defined. Most likely you have a color scheme that overrides the setting from vimrc.
                    – Andrey R

Make sure to place the highlight line after you set your colorscheme.
                    – FDinoff